# How can make sort by votes "by date", "by year"..?

Tags: php, mysql

What I am trying to implement is similar to what we have on SO. I want to rank posts by upvotes in last day, last month etc. My schema makes up two tables,

```
post(id, post, posted_on..)
vote(post_id, vote_value, date)
```

I hope the schema is pretty self explanatory. The problem being, if I sort "by day" by making a inner join on posts and vote and having a where clause('`votes.date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY`'), it does work as intended but fails to show the other posts. I mean the posts which haven't had vote in last day are completely ignored. What I want is that those posts be given low priority but do show up in the query.

While, I may think of using union operation but i was looking for another approach.

**Update**: Lets say, there are two posts, 1,2.

and votes table is like,

```
post_id       vote_value      date
1              1              2012-12-19
2              1              2012-12-10
```

If I query, as per my approach, then only the post - "1" will show up since I have put a date constraint but I want both to show up. Here is my query:

```
SELECT `id`, SUM(`votes`.`votes`) AS likes_t, `post`.* FROM `posts` JOIN `votes` ON (`id` = `votes`.`post_id`) WHERE `votes`.`date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of desired result ?

Comment: @aurel.g: I hope I have made it clear now.

Comment: @shubham : why not give a default low priority to every new entry

Comment: @BhavikShah: Thats what i want to know. How can I select rest of the of the rows when I have already put a date constraint? I UNION the only way?

Comment: can you post your whole existing query

Comment: Not really. If you don't want to filter on date, don't filter on date ?!

Comment: @aurel.g: See the query now. Damn me, i have always been a poor explainer.

Comment: Just a thought: `SELECT ori.post_id,d.vote_casts,w.vote_casts FROM vote ori LEFT JOIN (SELECT post_id,sum(vote_value) vote_casts FROM vote WHERE vote_date>=date_sub(curdate(),INTERVAL '1' DAY) GROUP BY post_id) d ON (ori.post_id=d.post_id) LEFT JOIN (SELECT post_id,sum(vote_value) vote_casts FROM vote WHERE vote_date>=date_sub(curdate(),INTERVAL '7' DAY) GROUP BY post_id) w ON (ori.post_id=w.post_id)`

Comment: I think UNION is the only option unless you do some changes in the where clause

Comment: @BhavikShah: Changes like??

Comment: @Shubham : like removing the where clause for date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show all posts, but only count the recent votes, this should do it:

```
SELECT `id`,
       SUM(IF(`votes`.`date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY, `votes`.`votes`, 0)) AS likes_t, 
       `post`.*
       FROM `posts` JOIN `votes` ON (`id` = `votes`.`post_id`)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I got it right:

`SELECT *, IF(vote.date>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 1, 0) as rate FROM post INNER JOIN vote ON (post.id=vote.post_id) ORDER BY rate DESC;`

```
+------+--------+---------+------+---------------------+------+
| id   | post   | post_id | vote | date                | rate |
+------+--------+---------+------+---------------------+------+
|    1 | first  |       1 |    1 | 2012-12-19 00:00:00 |    1 |
|    1 | first  |       1 |    1 | 2012-12-13 00:00:00 |    0 |
|    2 | second |       2 |    1 | 2012-12-10 00:00:00 |    0 |
+------+--------+---------+------+---------------------+------+
```